# Обновить таблицу переместив первое слово из одной ячейки в другую

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица с данными

```
id | invoice_name    | invoice_id
1  | INV123 - Name 1 | 
2  | INV345 - Name 2 |
```

Как мне написать такой запрос что бы он переместил INV123, INV345... в соседнюю ячейку invoice_id? Номер в названии всегда отделен пробелом.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось самому

```
UPDATE aos_invoices SET description = (SELECT LEFT(name,LOCATE(' ',name) - 1))
```

Comment: а что без селекта не работает? `UPDATE aos_invoices SET description = LEFT(name,LOCATE(' ',name) - 1)`

Comment: Не знал что и так можно, спасибо :)